# Elasticsearch in-place-update like solr

Tags: elasticsearch, solr

In **SOLR** I can use [In-Place-Update](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/updating-parts-of-documents.html#UpdatingPartsofDocuments-In-PlaceUpdates) to update the value of any fields. Here the value of `popularity` field will be incremented every time by **20** and add it to the the current value of popularity without considering any other things.

```
{
 "id":"mydoc",
 "price":{"set":99},
 "popularity":{"inc":20}
}
```

For **Elasticsearch**, I can also use the `_update` api using `script` to [In-Place-update](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html#_using_scripts_to_make_partial_updates).

```
POST /website/blog/1/_update
{
   "script" : "ctx._source.popularity+=20"
}
```

But my problem is I want to use the `_bulk` api using python to in-place-update multiple documents at one with some incremental values. [Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#bulk-update) I've seen the documentation on how to use the `_bulk` endpoint to set different values with **update** action payload. I'm just having some difficulties how can I make the same **POST JSON** datasets for `_bulk` with python elasticsearch client for the `script` update way.

Comment: Have you considered using [`helpers`](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html) module of the elasticsearch python library? May you please tell what did you try so far, what is not working?

Comment: Yeah I've tried that with `_bulk` and `bulk_stream` but every time its showing malformed script error. Finally I am getting the docs, processing it and using `_update` to update those documents :(

Comment: May you provide the code you use to send `bulk` with helpers and the error it gives?

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev thanks for you willingness, but I'm out off office now :), I'll share with you later. THanks